# how to use auto-focus concept in fixed focus camera without hardware

Tags: python-3.x, performance, opencv, authentication, camera

I am working a project like face recognition using webcam, in this project we use two types of cameras like fixed focus(Mercury hd professional webcam 1080p) and autofocus camera(Logitech C270), actual thing is the script working finely in logitech c270 with autofocus, but not efficiently in Mercury hd professional webcam 1080p, My question is atually is it possible we can working a autofocus concept in fixed focus camera like Mercury hd professional webcam 1080p. My script is full-of opencv python.[the code snippet for i make a autofocus function in opencv python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNRoW.jpg)

Comment: if your fixed focus can is out of focus (leading to a blurry image), yoz typically cant repair that by software. Maybe newer AI algorithms similar to superresolution cozld magically improve the image quality, but that's just a guess and probably a research topic.

Comment: the C270 has fixed focus, not autofocus. I own a C270. did you mean another type?

Answer (score 0):

you deal with a fixed-focus camera by turning its focus ring physically. if it doesn't have that easily accessible, you would have to void your device's warranty by opening it up and (physically) adjusting the lens. that isn't a difficult or dangerous operation but I will not detail it here. you can find good guides for adjusting the focus of a Logitech C270 online. I'm sure you can find that for your other device as well.